# Django REST nested objects validate

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My database:

```
User
-----------------------------------
id  |  name
-----------------------------------
1   |  Phuong Vu
-----------------------------------
Profile
-----------------------------------
user_id  |  phone_number
-----------------------------------
1        |  123456
-----------------------------------
```

My models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, blank=True)
```

My serializers:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        ##################################
        # I want get current instance here
        ##################################
        print self.instance
        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = Profile

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

This is in my view, I called is_valid 2 times in 2 ways to test:

```
profile_data = {
    'phone_number':'123456'
}
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=1)
setattr(user, 'profile', profile)
data = {
    'profile': profile_data
}
serializer = UserSerializer(
    user,
    data=data,
    partial=True
)
# This said 'Profile phone number is exist' 
# because ProfileSerialiser.instance is None
serializer.is_valid() 

# This is fine because ProfileSerialiser.instance is not None   
profile_serialiser = ProfileSerialiser(profile, data=profile_data, partial=True)
profile_serializer.is_valid()
```

After create serializer instance, `UserSerializer.instance` is not `None` but children `ProfileSerializer.instance` is `None`.

So how can I fix this issue? (Access to `self.instance` in `ProfileSerializer` after it has created via `UserSerialiser`)

Comment: Could you please add the exception out of curiosity?

Comment: you mention that you access`ProfileSerializer.instance`, but it's not in your code. where do you access it?

Comment: @iulian For example. `ProfileSerializer -> def validate(self, attrs): pass` and in this method I want to check that's new instance (`self.instance is None`) or from database (`self.instance is not None`)

Comment: @Wtower In database `profile(pk=1).phone_number is equal 123456`. If I validate via `ProfileSerialiser`, It will be fine.  But when I validated via `UserSerialize` It shown phone_number already exists (Because `ProfileSerializer.instance` which constructed via UserSerializer was None I guess).

Comment: Please post any additional information in your question by editing it and refrain doing so in comments.

Comment: Hi @Wtower, I updated more details for my question. Please take a look and help me when you can.